# Dynamically assign variable in Go template

Tags: go

I want to dynamically index a slice in my Go template.

index.html:

```
{{index .Animals 1}}
```

.go:

```
Animals := []string{"cat", "dog"}
```

This prints "dog" in the html file. However, I don't want to hard code 1 inside `{{index .Animals 1}}`, but assign a variable depending on changes in the javascript code. How do I do this?

eg.

index.html:

```
<body>
  <script>
    var indexNum = // get page num
  </script>
  {{index .Animals $indexNum}}
</body>
```

Comment: Your question is clear, but unclear... So you want to have Animals assigned depending on something in your Javascript code? Can you post some psuedo code or something of what you expect to happen?

Comment: Updated. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, you'd need to have like an ajax request after the page loads if you wanted to do something like that